# How to transform formulas in conjunctive normal forms?

Tags: logic

I tried the INSEADO method to transform $((\neg p\wedge q)) \vee (p \wedge \neg q)) $ into a conjunctive normal form but I get lost:

at

$((\neg p \vee p) \wedge  (\neg p \vee \neg q)) \vee((q \vee p)\wedge (q \vee \neg q)) $

**what can I do next as far as two closes seems to be empty?**

Comment: $\lnot p \lor p \equiv TRUE$ and $TRUE \land \mathcal A \equiv \mathcal A$.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean $((\neg p\land q)\lor(p\land \neg q))$ (note $q$ and not $g$ at the end)?

What you use is that $\neg\phi\lor\phi\leftrightarrow\phi\lor\neg\phi\leftrightarrow T$ (and $\psi\land T\leftrightarrow T\land\psi\leftrightarrow \psi$). So you get $(\neg p\lor \neg q)\land (p\lor q)$.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the [distributive rule of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) to your expression yields

$$(\lnot p \lor (p \land \lnot q)) \land (q \lor (p \land \lnot q)) $$

Applying it again, leads to

$$((\lnot p \lor p) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)) \land ((q \lor p) \land (q \lor \lnot q)) $$

Note the middle $\land$ operator which is different to your intermediate result.

As pointed out by Mauro, you can then replace $(\lnot p \lor p)$ and $(q \lor \lnot q)$ by $true$.

The resulting [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) consists of two clauses:

$$(\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \land (q \lor p)$$